# Trigger for TabItem.IsSelected doesn't work

Tags: wpf, styles, selecteditem

I want to have selected tab background set to red and unselected to green. However only unselected tab is colored on green when changing. Selected remains white.

```xml
        <TabControl Background="LightGray" Name="MainTabControl">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Main" />
        <TabItem Header="Optimizer" />
    </TabControl>
```

[image: enter ifdsfdsre]

Answer (score 6):

Override the `TabItem`'s `ControlTemplate` and add the trigger to it

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border"  >
                            <ContentPresenter  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          ContentSource="Header" >                                   
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">                                
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />                                
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />                                                                
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**EDIT**

to keep the original `tabitem` style and add you background colors, from vs designer right click on the `tabitem` and select EditTemplate > Edit a Copy, then update the `TabItem.Static.Background` Gardian brush which is responsible for the non selected tab color, and `TabItem.Selected.Background` Brush which is responsible for the Selected tab color:

```
  //..
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItem.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Static.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#ECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Border" Color="#7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Background" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Border" Color="#D9D9D9"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="Red"/>
    //..
```

**Or**

or you can use a `templateBinding` in both the `mainBorder` and `innerBorder` to the `Background` property (initially only the `mainBorder`  was `templateBinded` to the `background` property), then add you trigger to the `controlTemplate` triggers,

```
<Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="mainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
                            <Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    </Grid>
```

and add your trigger at the end

```
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                            </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

and that should response your second question

Comment: Many thanks for that. I have to more questions:
1. What if I want to keep default TabItem style? Currently colors work fine but layout looks a bit different from the original.
2. What is the reason that my code doesn't work?

Comment: If you wan't to keep the original tabItem style and change only the background based on the "IsSelectedPrperty" you need to edit the tabItem Template using Blend, or simply from the visual studio designer click EditTemplate>Edit a Copy and in the generated style change the generated style's background colors

Comment: the fact that your origInal code didn't work is probably due to the fact that TabItem panel when an item is selected wasn't TemplateBinded to the Background property, you can figure that by simply checking the Generated TabItem controlTemplate and how the triggers manages the selected tab

Comment: It would be interesting to know the reasons of the problem, and how the solution fixes them, else this tends to encourage [voodoo programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming).

Comment: Please checkout the above comments, il n'y a ni de voodoo ni de doodoo!